# add small np.array to larger np.array

Tags: python

In `R`, I can easily add a smaller vector to a larger vector (assuming length of larger vector is a multiple of length of smaller vector)

```
a <- seq(1,10,1)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
b <- seq(1,2,1)
# [1] 1 2
a+b
# [1]  2  4  4  6  6  8  8 10 10 12
```

Is there an easy way to do this in `Python`?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1, 10)
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.arange(1,4)
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

What I tried

```
a + b?
np.add(a, b)?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy does not simply assume that you might want to repeat `b` before adding it to `a`, you must tell it to do that yourself.

The system by which you can do that is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). You create a 2D array by adding another axis of exactly the same length of `b`. Adding `b` to that 2D array has exactly the desired behaviour.

And afterwards we flatten the array back to 1D.

```
(a.reshape(-1, len(b)) + b).ravel()
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my example code contained a typo. Will accept your answer when it allows me.